# What happens after Google Drive Android API deprecation？

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have an application on the Google Play Store using Google Drive Android API.
Since the API itself is deprecated and all connection will be refused after December 6, 2019, what will happen to the ongoing application?

For example, I am using API stated below in my application.

```
addApi(Drive.API);  
addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER);
```

Will the application hang or crash when I call on the API, or it will just return any error codes?

Answer (score 0):

They shut down it, so is the same as when you've no connection.
I quote the last part of [that](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-api-client) article:

> If you call addApi() and the GoogleApiClient is unable to connect
>   successfully to that API, the entire connection operation for that
>   client fails and triggers the onConnectionFailed() callback.

In the same article read the section 'Ignoring API Connection Failures' for the how-to avoid it :)

L-

Comment: But what happens with the game positions users had saved using the Drive Android API? Also reading the [migration page](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation), there is mentioned on 2 places, that as saving game state in Drive is an [Offline sync](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation#offline_sync), and is likely to be removed from Drive in the future. I consider this as a main Google's fail!